# Making a calculator that translates a string to ints and chars

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm working through a list of practice problems to beef up my C++ skills (I'm a beginner), this one is stumping me.

> Make a program that takes input from the user of a calculation (e.g. "2+2") and outputs the 
>   answer (e.g. 4). It shouldn't matter if there are spaces or the formatting of the user's 
>   input, so long as the basics (2 numbers and one connecting function) are fulfilled.

I think I have the basic idea down, I just don't understand two critical parts:

1) How take the input from the user as a string and put it into an array.

2) How to take members of an array and reconfigure them as a string.

Comment: Why would you want to put it in an array?

Comment: My thought wsa that if I put it in an array I could 'search' through it using an iterator like
`code` while(user_input[i] != '+')
`code`      first_num = user_input[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you seem to have an idea what you want to do, I'll just answer the questions. Go ahead and try. :)

To read from the console in C++ you can include the iostream-library and use cin <<.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
 string yourVar;
 // ...  
 cin >> yourVar;
 //...
}
```

You should then be able to use the string like an array e.g. char c = yourVar[2];

Answer (score 0):

Search about tokenizing and grammar. A very nice example which fits the description of your problem is thoroughly presented in the book : [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321543726) among other things.

This will not only allow you to solve this problem but it will also allow you to create a much more powerful calculator, taking into account things such as operator precedence, parentheses, curly brackets etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference!! I'll check it out!